# Android: Passing Touch Events from View

Tags: android, android-layout, opengl-es, touch

In my app, I have a `RelativeLayout` that contains two other `RelativeLayouts`.  The first `RelativeLayout` is used for an OpenGL view.  The second is used to place `Buttons` and other `Views`.  I am able to process touch events fine in OpenGL, unless they take place on one of the `Views`.

This is normally fine, but at times I want the OpenGL view to receive the event as well, but the View in front of it is always consuming the touch event.  I have tried using the following, with no luck:

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)
{
    onTouchEvent(ev);
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather than overwrite `onInterceptTouchEvent`, I needed `dispatchTouchEvent` which is a method of Activity.  In `dispatchTouchEvent` I distributed the `MotionEvent` as needed.  Here is an example:

```
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev){
    mGLView.onTouchEvent(ev); //The openGL view
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}
```